# How do I redirect to the "Error" view page after an AJAX call?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an Ajax calling an HTTP Post Action method in the controller.

This action method is throwing a simple exception message.

I have decorated the controller with my own custom handler attribute with the following:

```
 public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {

        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled) {
            string actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            Type controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
            var method = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName);
            var returnType = method.ReturnType;
            string controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

            HandleErrorInfo model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

            // redirect on error
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult {
                ViewName = "Error",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model)
            };
        }

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
```

The issue with above is that for some reason, with a POST method, my page doesn't get redirected to the Error View. However, if I call an action method that has been decorated with the [HttpGet], my redirect will work properly.

Is it possible to redirect an AJAX method to the Error View as I would like the Error view page to handle all errors?

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page, and ajax calls do not redirect.

Comment: if the action throws error, the `ajax failure event` will trigger, in that write code for redirection to the error page

Answer (score 2):

You can attach global ajax error handler like this:

```
 $(function() {
   $(document).ajaxError(function(xhr, props) {
     if (props.status >= 200 && props.status < 300 || props.status === 304) {
       //all is well
     } else {
       alert("error");
       window.location = "/Error/CustomError";
     }
   });
 });
```